# How to remove HTML tags in PDF?

Tags: php, html, pdf

How to remove the HTML tags?

I want to remove the HTML tags in the PDF view. Look at the picture below. Please help me with this.

This is my code:

```
$string1 = $_POST["editor1"];
$string1 = str_replace("<p>", "", $string1);
$string2 = str_replace("&nbsp; ", " ", $string1);
$string2 = explode("</p>", $string1);
```

This is my output:

```
foreach ($string2 as $key) {
    $pdf->Multicell(0,3,$key);
}

?>
```

[image: my pdf file]

Comment: probably what you are seeing is double encoded html entites. Track the original input to the source and see if you have `&amp;nbsp;` in your input. In general if you want to get rid of the entities you should use something like [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) instead of str_replace

Answer (score 6):

The `strip_tags()`  function strips a string from HTML, XML, and PHP tags.

`strip_tags(string,allow)`

`$string1 = strip_tags($string1);`

*Update

-Allowing certain tags to be get printed.

`echo strip_tags("Hello <b><i>SO!</i></b>","<b>");`

prints Hello **SO!**

Comment: can you show me the right way to do it? get one example from my code. thank you very much.

Comment: `$string1` = strip_tags($string1);

Answer (score 2):

You could use following code for replacement of special characters in pdf formatted text. I have used this code in my java project, and it is working fine there. I have changed this to php for you.

```
    $string1=str_replace("&nbsp", " ", $string1 );
    $string1=str_replace("&", "&amp;", $string1 );
    $string1=str_replace(">", "&gt;", $string1 );
    $string1=str_replace("<", "&lt;", $string1 );
    $string1=str_replace("&agrave;", "&#192;", $string1 );
    $string1=str_replace("&euml;", "&#203;", $string1 );
    $string1=str_replace("\"", "&quot;", $string1 );
    $string1=str_replace("&lt;br /&gt;", "<br />", $string1 );
    $string1=str_replace("&eacute;", "&#233;", $string1 );
    $string1=str_replace("à", "&#224;", $string1 );
```

Comment: You should use an array with the search and another with the replace, instead of running this function a bunch of times.

Answer (score 0):

**strip_tags()** is the best way. **str_replace()** required more code.